Simultaneous multiple simulator sessions
Investigate the feasibility and implementation of simultaneous multiple simulator sessions to support test scenarios that require multiple users logged in simultaneously using Appium.
Currently i am finding a way to open multiple window-session at the same time while running test case in mobile automation. I didn't tried anything yet because single window session is working fine. But for most of the test cases i have to open multiple window session at same time to validate user messages.

My question is, i am developing mobile automation scripts, in some of
the scenarios ex. in first window i have to login with user1 & same
time i have to open another window/session/tab in simulator and login
with user2 and verify message sent by user1, currently what is
happening i have to logout user1 and login with user2 on same panel
but in actual way we have to open user2 in another separate/concurrent
session so that any message/call/videoCalls verification possible.

Scenario:

Login with user1 in first window
Login with user2 in second window
Send a message from user1 to user2 in first window
Verify user2 received a message in second window

Scenario:

Login with user1 in first window
Login with user2 in second window
User1 calls to user2 in first window
User2 receives a call from user1 in second window
Wait for 5 seconds and ends the call in first window

Currently using:

Android Studio/Android Emulator
Appium
Docker

Thanks in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Marcy
My question is, i am developing mobile automation scripts, in some of the scenarios ex. in first window i have to login with user1 & same time i have to open another window/session/tab in simulator and login with user2 and verify message sent by user1,
currently what is happening i have to logout user1 and login with user2 on same panel but in actual way we have to open user2 in another separate/concurrent session so that any message/call/videoCalls verification possible.
I have updated/Enhanced my question in detailed scenarios
